# how do I perform a HEAD operation with Google.Cloud.Storage.V1

Tags: .net, google-cloud-storage

I've been pretty frustrated trying to find a good developer reference for Google.Cloud.Storage.V1

I want to do a simple HEAD operation to check a bucket exists: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/head-bucket#example

How do I do this with the library? I can't find a method for this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/tree/master/apis/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1

Comment: BigQuery storage API isn't the Cloud Storage API. You are trying to perform the same thing in 2 different worlds. Of course you don't find how, because you can't!

Comment: fixed typo not using big query just bucket storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML-API method tells you if the bucket exist and if you have the right on it.

> Indicates if a bucket exists and whether the requester has READ access to it.

You can do the equivalent with the [GET bucket rest API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get)

Thus, the getBucket method is the closest to what you want to achieve